# jquery space invaders project, what should i do to kill the aliens?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm writing a space-invaders-game code, and i don't know how to kill the aliens with the bullets. i tried removing the element when both the ship and the bullet reach the same position from the top and the left, but it didn't work with me, and i don't know if the implementation of it was wrong or the idea itself.(long and ugly code, i know, but please tell me if you have any suggestions that might improve it, i'm still a beginner :D)

```
  <script>

    $(document).ready(function () {
        var key = {l: 0, r: 0, s: 0};

        //arrow keys and spacebar down
        $(document).keydown(function (e) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 37: //left arrow
                    key.l = 1;
                    break;
                case 39: //right arrow
                    key.r = 1;
                    break;
                case 32: //spacebar
                    key.s = 1;

                    break;
            }
        });
        //arrow keys and spacebar up
        $(document).keyup(function (e) {
            switch (e.keyCode) {
                case 37: //left arrow
                    key.l = 0;
                    break;
                case 39: //right arrow
                    key.r = 0;
                    break;
                case 32: //spacebar
                    key.s = 0;
                    break;
            }
        });


        Movement();

        //the movement of the ship with the arrow keys and shooting usnig spacebar
        function Movement() {
            requestAnimationFrame(Movement);

        if ($('.bullet').length > 0) {
            $('.bullet').css({"top": "-=20"});
            if ($('.bullet').position().top < 0)
                $('.bullet').remove();
        }
        if($('#ship').position().left>890 )
            key.r=0;
        else if($('#ship').position().left<=0)
            key.l=0;

        if (key.l) {
            $("#ship").css({"left": $('#ship').position().left - 10})
        }
        if (key.r) {
            $("#ship").css({"left": $('#ship').position().left + 10})
        }
        if (key.s) {

            $('#myDiv').append('<img class="bullet" src="bullet.png" width="40" height="100">');
            if($())

            $('.bullet').css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "top": $('#ship').position().top - 100,
                "left": $('#ship').position().left + 30
             });
            }
         }
        createAliens();
        //creating aliens 
        function createAliens() {

            for(var i=1;i<=10;i++) {
                $('#myDiv').append('<img id="alien'+i+'" src="alien.ico" width="70" height="70">');
            }
            $('#alien1').css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: parseInt(Math.random() * 940 + 1)
                });
            $('#alien2').css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: parseInt(Math.random() * 940 + 1)
            });
            $('#alien3').css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: parseInt(Math.random() * 940 + 1)
            });
            $('#alien4').css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: parseInt(Math.random() * 940 + 1)
            });

            $('#alien5').css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: parseInt(Math.random() * 940 + 1)
            });
            $('#alien6').css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: parseInt(Math.random() * 940 + 1)
            });
            $('#alien7').css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: parseInt(Math.random() * 940 + 1)
            });
            $('#alien8').css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: parseInt(Math.random() * 940 + 1)
            });
            $('#alien9').css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: parseInt(Math.random() * 940 + 1)
            });
            $('#alien10').css({
                position: "absolute",
                left: parseInt(Math.random() * 940 + 1)
            });
            timer();
        }
        //timer for aliens to move from top to bottom
        function timer() {
            var delay1=parseInt(Math.random()*(3000-1000)+1000);
            var delay2=parseInt(Math.random()*(3000-1000)+1000);
            var delay3=parseInt(Math.random()*(3000-1000)+1000);
            var delay4=parseInt(Math.random()*(3000-1000)+1000);
            var delay5=parseInt(Math.random()*(3000-1000)+1000);
            var delay6=parseInt(Math.random()*(3000-1000)+1000);
            var delay7=parseInt(Math.random()*(3000-1000)+1000);
            var delay8=parseInt(Math.random()*(3000-1000)+1000);
            var delay9=parseInt(Math.random()*(3000-1000)+1000);
            var delay10=parseInt(Math.random()*(3000-1000)+1000);

            setInterval(function () {

                $('#alien1').css({
                  top: "+=20"
                });
                if ($('#alien1').position().top > 450){
                    $('#alien1').remove();
                    location.reload();}
                },delay1);
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#alien2').css({
                    top: "+=20"
                });
                if ($('#alien2').position().top > 450){
                    $('#alien2').remove();
                    location.reload();}

            }, delay2);
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#alien3').css({
                    top: "+=20"
                });
                if ($('#alien3').position().top > 450){
                    $('#alien3').remove();
                    location.reload();}

                }, delay3);

            setInterval(function () {
                $('#alien4').css({
                    top: "+=20"
                });
                if ($('#alien4').position().top > 450){
                    $('#alien4').remove();
                    location.reload();}

            },delay4);
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#alien5').css({
                    top: "+=20"
                });
                if ($('#alien5').position().top > 450){
                    $('#alien5').remove();
                    location.reload();}

                    },delay5);
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#alien6').css({
                    top: "+=20"
                });
                if ($('#alien6').position().top > 450){
                    $('#alien6').remove();
                    location.reload();}

            }, delay6);
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#alien7').css({
                    top: "+=20"
                });
                if ($('#alien7').position().top > 450){
                    $('#alien7').remove();
                    location.reload();}

            },delay7);
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#alien8').css({
                    top: "+=20"
                });
                if ($('#alien8').position().top > 450){
                    $('#alien8').remove();
                    location.reload();}

                    },delay8);
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#alien9').css({
                    top: "+=20"
                });
                if ($('#alien9').position().top > 450){
                    $('#alien9').remove();
                    location.reload();}

            }, delay9);
            setInterval(function () {
                $('#alien10').css({
                    top: "+=20"
                });
                if ($('#alien10').position().top > 450){
                    $('#alien10').remove();
                    location.reload();}
            }, delay10)
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You may want to consider adding a jsfiddle so that people can see your code in action. Removeing it won't work, because you are constantly removing and replacing them to move the aliens. You have to figure out a way to store whether an alien is being rendered or not.

Comment: hard-coding the IDs of your individual aliens smells like bad code. What about storing them in an array, then you can operate on them all consistently using the same pieces of code. There's a lot of repetition here. Also, every time you call location.reload(); it's going to reset your entire page - is that what you want?

Comment: Was did your condition that did a comparison of the positions look like? 
Should be comparing rectangles of the bullet and the object. 
https://jsfiddle.net/9wzxqspy/